# How do I enter a filepath to save a new file to using the OS X "save file" dialog?

Tags: macos, dialog

I found this annoying bug in OS X. Steps to reproduce:

1. Open any GUI text editor.
2. Create a new buffer.
3. `Cmd+Shift+S` to bring up the "Save file" dialog.
4. Start typing the filepath to save to. Anything with a `~` or a `/` in it.

Expected behavior: I am allowed to type.

Actual behavior: As soon as I type a `~` or `/` character, I get an annoying pop-up saying "Go to the folder".

Is there a way to fix this bug, or work around it so that I can type filepaths without the UI getting in my way?

Comment: It's not a bug, it's a feature. A faster way would be to have the folder you want to save to visible & just drag it to the save dialog.

Comment: @Tetsujin anything that stops me getting stuff done while providing no benefits is a bug. By that measure, this is certainly a bug.

Comment: @Tetsujin I can understand what he means as you can not set the file-extension and you have to hit return twice. But I don't see it as a bug either as it's a graphical way in a graphical UI. If you want to do it plainly with keyboard-solutions you might have to use a few more keys than in some other operating systems.....

Comment: I understand what you both mean, no issues. I still think the fastest way is to drag the intended folder to the file-picker [or use Default Folder, which I do, but that's a paid util]

Comment: @heiglandreas @Tetsujin there's some confusion here: "graphical" vs "textual" UI is orthogonal to whether I am able to type in a literal filepath. If I have a filepath on the clipboard, it should be no more than `Cmd+Shift+S`, `Cmd+V`, `Return`. Anything more than that and the user interface has a bug. I should add that the equivalent bug exists for the "Open File" dialog.